# Partial Matching While Searching in a List of Strings in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list

In List.Contains method, how do i change the following linq query to accomodate partial searching like we do in sql with **LIKE**

```
AllDegrees.Listt = new List<string>();
.....
.....
.....
.....
var query = from q in query
join ce in context.CandidateEducations
on q.c.Candidate_OID equals ce.Candidate_OID
where AllDegrees.Listt.Contains(ce.Degree)
select q;
```

The actual scenario is that I have kaaal, jaaaal, baaal, maaal in AllDegrees.Listt . Now if ce.Degree is ka or al or ja or aa, that row should be included in my result set.

Comment: where AllDegrees.Listt.IndexOf(ce.Degree) !=-1 ? not sure.

Comment: i just want to accommodate partial string search from inside a List of strings, pasted above is just an example how I thought i could do this.

Comment: ignore ! in the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AllDegrees.Listt.Where(x => x.Contains("your string")).Any();
```

Comment: definitely not useful, this statement returns List<myType> where as what required is bool.

Comment: Erm... `i just want to accommodate partial string search from inside a List of strings` which is what this does. Nowhere do you state that it should return a bool? Maybe you should refine your question. Regardless, updated anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check this,

```
   private List<string> findDegreesLoop()
   {
        var list1 = new List<string>();
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        var list3 = new List<string>();

        foreach (var degree in list2)
        {
            var matches = list1.Where(q => q.Contains(degree)).ToList();
            if (matches.Any())
            {
               list3.AddRange(matches);
            }
        }
return list3;
 }


  private List<string> findDegreesLinq()
 {
        var list1 = new List<string>();
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        var list3 = new List<string>();

        foreach (var matches in list2.Select(degree => list1.Where(q =>     q.Contains(degree)).ToList()).Where(matches => matches.Any()))
        {
            list3.AddRange(matches);
        }
return list3;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what your are looking for. Here is a simple example which implements contains (~ SQL LIKE) method.

```
    context.CandidateEducations.Where(d=>d.ToLower().Trim().Contains(MyVariable.ToLower().Trim()))
```

Comment: Just noticed your below reply. The above query will also return a list. To convert it to a bool you may use MyList.Any()

Comment: doesnt work ^ (with the fix provided in comment)

Comment: You have added some more explanations to your question, which is good. Check my below reply.